# How use SELECT in append query in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In MS Access, I created a query by create Menu-> Query Design (with name `Query3`).

I want use it in an SQL command in another query but when I run it got this error:

> **Syntax error on query expression 'select f1'**

SQL command

```sql
INSERT INTO boors (boors.Nemad, boors.Volumn, boors.Price, 
                   boors.LastPrice, boors.LastPerc, boors.LastPr, 
                   boors.LastPer, boors.MinPrice, boors.MaxPrice, 
                   boors.distance, boors.inout, boors.Power) 
values (select f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12 FROM Query3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are mixing the SQL used for inserting values and inserting from a table/query. As you are doing the latter, your SQL should look like:

```
INSERT INTO boors (Nemad, Volumn)
SELECT F1, F2
FROM Query3
```

Regards,